# Mixing of shaders in 3DS Max 2010

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max

As a Blender user, I know that shaders are mixed in a way that there’s always a 1.000 value in the mixing, because the mixing works as a transitional number between the first shader and the second shader. Here is what I mean -

- Diffuse and Glossy shader alone - 
  [image]
  [image]
- Diffuse and Glossy shader with a mix value of 0.200 - 
  [image]
- Diffuse and Glossy shader with a mix value of 0.800 - 
  [image]

Which means that the higher the value on the first shader, the lower the value on the second shader, which is imitating of the real world shading. Maybe that is the case in the newer versions of 3DS Max with the Slate editor. But does 3DS Max 2010 mixes shaders in that way or they would have to be adjusted manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender shaders don't mix like in real world or professional packages, I don't even know why the choose 1000 instead of 1.00, which is the maximum value a pixel can store in 32 bit. The [Blend Shader](http://www.3dmax-tutorials.com/Blend_Material.html) in 3DS needs to be adjusted manually, and it works in the same way as in Blender (or even Photoshop), but instead of using 1000 it uses percentage, more user friendly of course.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. It is "1.000" value. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Vladimir, I added an useful link to my answer (blend shader).